# How common is it for recommendation letters to be sent directly from the writer to the recipient?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter, reference-request, international

Something that I frequently read on academia.SE is that recommendation letters, in most circumstances, are sent directly from the person writing the letter to the person/committee reading the letter, and is never to be seen by the person the recommendation letter is about. Invariably, there is also a comment saying that this is mainly US-specific.

So I'm curious, what is the actual situation, worldwide? Which is more common: the writer sending directly the letter to the recipient of the letter, or the writer giving the letter to the applicant, who in turn sends the letter to the actual recipient?

In my own limited experience, when I had to apply for PhD program funding (in France) I had to send my advisor's letter myself to the committee along with all the other documents, whereas when I applied for funding to attend a conference in a German institute, my advisor had to send the letter himself. So it doesn't look like it's strictly limited to the USA, but it's not a practice followed everywhere either.

Comment: *"So it doesn't look like it's strictly limited to the USA, but it's not a practice followed everywhere either."* Haven't you answered your own question here? What do you expect in addition to this?

Comment: @xLeitix Something based on more than my own two anecdotes... For all I know, maybe the process I had to follow was very unusual for Germany, or the process I had to follow for PhD funding was unique to France, or [insert random speculation here]. I don't even know if it's a practice followed 100% of the time in the US, too. I had hoped maybe people here had some concrete data about this.

Comment: I added the [tag:reference-request] tag, though I'm unsure whether there exists an actual survey or similar. Personal observation in Germany: I needed reference letters for my scholarship, and these went directly to the [Studienstiftung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studienstiftung).

Comment: We generally have external reviewers instead of recommendation letters in Finland. Coming from that background, the entire concept of recommendation letters seems dubious to me.

Comment: From my experience in the UK and Canada, all reference letters were sent directly to the recipient (electronically).

Comment: From my experience in applying to a Japanese university, sending a sealed envelope was okay, and it does not matter if the student sends it or the referee.

Comment: I applied to two schools in Germany and the Netherlands. The German school asked for a letters to be send from the writer, the Dutch asked for the contact information to recommender and then they wrote him directly and asked for a skype call.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience in Australia, letters that pass through the hands of the candidate are only used for very junior positions: jobs after high-school and sometimes first graduate jobs. For other positions, candidates are asked as part of the application process to list the contact details of referees, and the selection committee will get in touch with the referees directly -- usually by phone, sometimes by email.

I'm not sure whether my experience is typical.